# Output of make command FBReader open source - /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llinebreak

Tags: software-installation, make, opencv

I am new to Ubuntu. I want to make a FBReader open source project.
please help me out where I am lacking?

```
Creating libzltext.so.0.14.0 .../usr/bin/ld: **cannot find -llinebreak
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**
make[1]: *** [libzltext.so.0.14.0] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [FBReader/README.build](https://github.com/geometer/FBReader/blob/master/README.build):

```
FBReader requires
** expat -- library for XML parsing. AFAIK, all popular destributions
includes package with name like 'expat-dev' or 'libexpat-dev'.
If you cannot find expat in your distribution, please visit
http://expat.sourceforge.net
** libz and libbz2 -- libraries for zip and bzip2 (de)compression
** UI library -- this depends on your target platform. For desktop,
Qt library, version 3.* or 4.*
OR
GTK+ library, version >= 2.4
should be installed
** liblinebreak (http://vimgadgets.cvs.sourceforge.net/vimgadgets/common/tools/linebreak/)
   library for line breaking in a Unicode sequence
** libfribidi -- for bidirectional text support
** lincurl, version >= 7.17 -- for network libraries integration
** libsqlite3
```

You need to install from source `liblinebreak`, download this [tarball](http://vimgadgets.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/vimgadgets/common/tools/linebreak/?view=tar) and type the following commands where you extracted the archive:

```
 sudo apt-get install automake
 ./bootstrap
 aclocal
 autoconf
 automake --add-missing
 ./configure
 make
 sudo make install
```

Comment: I extracted this archive in FBReader root folder.

when i type ./configure it says -   **harkirat@saurabh:~/Downloads/FBReader-master$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory**

Comment: @HarkiratSethi: I've added the missing steps. Please try the new commands before calling `./configure`

Comment: Thank you :) how to remove this error  cannot remove `/usr/share/zlibrary/encodings/Big5': Permission denied
how to make install in a user mode? having no privileges being root?

Comment: @HarkiratSethi: Just call configure this way to install in your home folder: `./configure --prefix=$HOME/myapps`. Then just run `make install` (without sudo)